# How to hide this GUI at the time of screenshot?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I have created this GUI to take screenshot but when I am taking screenshot than in the screenshot image the GUI is also showing and I do not want this GUI to be captured in the image. Only screenshot display should be captured.
This is the Image
[Here is the Image of Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLHMX.png)

Comment: You can use `after` and wait while the `root` gets hidden

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)